# Writeline() add empty line at end of file [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-manipulation

This is my code to delete last line of file but after rewriting it to the same file there is an extra empty line that exist.

```
lines = open('file.csv', 'r').readlines() 
del lines[-1] 
open('file.csv', 'w').writelines(lines)
```

Notice that initial file has two lines: [image: Initial File]

> ```
>  Orange[1st line of csv]
>  Blue[2nd line of csv]
> ```

Notice that the last text/line of file is deleted, but there is extra empty line: [image]

> ```
>  Orange[1st line of csv]
>  [2nd line still exist but empty]
> ```

My goal is to have that extra line to be deleted. Thank you in advance!

Comment: A well-formed text file always has a trailing newline on each line. In some sense this produces an "empty string" which can be rendered as a line with no content at the very end of the file in some programs. It's not really clear from your question if this is what concerns you; if it is, my advice would be to not worry about it. Not writing a newline at the end of the last line is technically trivial, but usually not a good idea if you want your text files to be interoperable with other programs.

Comment: @tripleee, if my program need to rewrite again on the same file, my concern is that I got Orange[1st line] Empy line[2nd line] and then New Color[3rd line], this shows that I ended up with some empty lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the newline is not from the line with `'Orange'`, but rather from the line with `'Blue'`, which is in fact `'Blue\n'`.

Accordingly, you should do something like this:

```
with open('file.csv', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()[:-1]
    lines[-1] = lines[-1].strip()
    f.seek(0)
    f.writelines(lines)
    f.truncate()
```

Note, in particular:

- The use of `with` to open files to prevent leaking file objects
- A single call to `open` in read/write mode (this is more of a matter of style)

Contents of `file.csv`:

```
Blue
```

Comment: I tried befoew the strip(), except for adding f.seek and f.truncate, I will check further for what it does,

Comment: @bumbumpaw the file object you get when you call `open` maintains a pointer to the current position in the file. After reading, the pointer is at the end, so you need to go back to the beginning with `seek` to begin writing. When `write` is called, you overwrite *what is already there*, so when you're done you need to call `truncate` to remove the rest of the old data, if any.